# About Heine definition for limits of functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if and only if for all sequences $x_n$ (with $x_n$ not equal to $a$ for all $n$) converging to $a$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $L$.

This is Heine definition for the limits of functions. I have a question about this:

- How can I prove that "for all sequences"? I mean, say I have to prove the limit of $\sin(n)$ when $n$ goes to infinity doesn't exist. I can choose two sequences $a_n = \pi n $ and $b_n = \frac{\pi}{2}n$ and show the limits are different, hence the limit doesn't exist. Fine.

But what when I have a function and "I know" it has a limit? I cannot prove ALL the sequences... How to deal in this case?

Comment: It isn't all sequences, it is all sequences converging to $x$, so you need to use the fact that these sequence converge to $x$ that is for some any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a sufficiently large $N$ (depending upon your sequence of choice) and $n>N$ you will have that each $x_n$ is within an $\epsilon$ of $x$ (i.e. $\vert x-x_n\vert<\epsilon$), and this is what you must use

Comment: @StevenCreech The sequences still remain infinite (or too many), I cannot prove them all.

Comment: Why can’t you work with the word "ALL"? You can prove that all numbers greater than 2 are greater than 1 and there are no problems with that, right? You need to prove some implication.

Comment: I mean you take an arbitrary sequence converging to $x$, I mean there are infinitely many of them, so you can't enumerate them

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that might help, let $f(x)=2x$, then if you want to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)=2$, then what you do is say let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n\rightarrow 1$, you then wish to show that the sequence $f(x_n)\rightarrow 2$. Notice, I didn't pick a particular sequence, it is just an arbitrary sequence, but I must use the property that $x_n\rightarrow 1$ in the proof.

Now let us show that $f(x_n)\rightarrow 2$ that is we wish to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ we want to show that there is some $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have that $\vert f(x_n)-2\vert<\epsilon$ or equivalently, we wish to show that $\vert 2x_n-2\vert<\epsilon$ or again equivalently we must have that $2\vert x_n-1\vert<\epsilon$ or $\vert x_n-1\vert<\epsilon/2$. Now we see this looks a lot like the convergence of the sequence $x_n\rightarrow 1$ (which is what we must use), to find our $N$ we can just use the $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have that $\vert x_n-1\vert<\epsilon/2$ (which is guaranteed by the assumption that $x_n\rightarrow 1$. Then from the above, we see using this $N$ the fact that $\vert x_n-1\vert<\epsilon/2$ is equivalent to $\vert f(x_n)-2\vert<\epsilon$, so we conclude that $f(x_n)\rightarrow 2$.